# Square root in a general field

Tags: algorithms, field-theory, roots, finite-fields

In $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ there are obvious ways to calculate the square root of a quadratic residue. For finite fields of order $p$ we can use the Tonelli–Shanks algorithm. How about for a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^q}$ of order $p^q$? Or more general, for a back-box field?

Comment: Clearly (I think) the term "quadratic residue" is just being used here as an awkward synonym for "perfect square in the field I care about right now."

Comment: Black box finite field is a tall order. You would need to, for example, get an idea of the order $m$ of the element. If the order is odd (happens always when $p=2$) then you are in business: $x^{(m+1)/2}=\sqrt x$. In a field of order $Q=p^q$, you can do the usual trick if $Q+1$ is divisible by four. This is because if $x\in\Bbb{F}_Q$ is a non-zero square, then $x^{(Q-1)/2}=1$, so $y=x^{(Q+1)/4}$ works as a $\sqrt x$ if one exists.

Comment: Of course, if $p=2$, then $x^{2^{q-1}}$ will be a square root of $x$.